# How can I search in a big data collection on server side without publishing everything in meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, publish-subscribe, typeahead

I'm a newbie to Meteor. I need to build up a text search system with typeahead-like feature using Meteor js. My collection on the server side has about 1 million words, so it's impossible to publish them all (my page will take forever to load so I'm assuming the collection is so large that the sync takes forever). However, each time, my system needs to search within the whole collection. Anyone has suggestions about how to do this? Thanks a lot

Comment: There are plenty of typehead packages you can try and many of them support server-side search. Look on atmospherejs.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is server logic. You have to calculate your stuff with a server method:

```
Meteor.methods({'myGreatTextSearch': (someParameters) => {
  // TEXT AGGREGATION here
  return stuff
})
```

You can get 'stuff' on the client with

```
Meteor.call('myGreatTextSearch', someParameters)
```

Comment: Thanks! There's one thing I'm still confused about. As I also have to display part of potentially correct words, is it possible to do it without publish the collection at all?